# How to reinstall OEM copy of Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, windows-installation, reinstall

I have a laptop with Windows 11. It was installed when purchased. I would like to install another OS, without dual booting—wiping Win11 from the hard drive—but still be able to reinstall Windows 11 later.

I’m very comfortable installing Windows, from scratch, but I don’t know whether I could register the reinstalled copy. I don’t have a registration code.

Comment: You don't need any other license. You can reinstall anytime and it'll activate.

Comment: You may wish to download the ISO for Windows 11 install and test it to ensure it works. It should and your license is good but do test now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a full drive image. That should be the first task after buying a PC, so you can *always* revert to the original state, whether to undo changes, to clear personal data before returning or selling the PC, or to restore to another drive should the original fail.

Then you can wipe the drive, repeatedly install other operating systems, and then get back to *exactly* the state the PC was in at the time the image was made.

There are many free and commercial applications for most operating to make a drive image, such as [DriveImage XML](https://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm), [dd](https://blog.kubesimplify.com/the-complete-guide-to-the-dd-command-in-linux), [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/macrium_reflect_free_edition.html) and [commercial](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), and many [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/).

In addition to making the drive image, also create a bootable USB to *restore* the data. Most of the utilities mentioned above have directions for doing so.

BTW, making and restoring a drive image is **far** faster than reinstalling Windows, because

- Imaging software can use direct disk I/O, rather than create one file at a time, and because
- The *installation* process has to detect the hardware, then select *only* the appropriate drivers and install them, whereas those drivers are already in the drive image.

It is also *safer* than reinstalling from ISO, since the manufacturer likely used a customized WIM to install Windows and proprietary drivers not available from Microsoft.